# How to assign specific values to a factorial dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am calculating a summary (mean) from a set of locations. And then need to re-assign these mean values to the locations from where these means were calculated.

What I did was to calculate those means and tried to create a new variable (average.yield) that assign the mean yield of the locations to each individual location.

```
cultivar <- c("cultivar_A", "cultivar_B")
data1 <- expand.grid(locs, cultivar)
yield <- c(7000, 5000, 2000, 7000, 6000, 5000) 
data1$yield <-  yield
colnames(data1) <- c("locs", "cultivar", "yield")


mean.yield.loc <- data1 %>%
                    group_by(locs) %>%
                    summarise(mean.yield = mean(yield))

data1 %>% 
        group_by(locs, cultivar) %>%
        mutate(average.yield = mean.yield.loc$mean.yield)
```

I expected something like this..

```
locs   cultivar yield   average.yield
Loc_1 cultivar_A  7000  7000
Loc_2 cultivar_A  5000  5500
Loc_3 cultivar_A  2000  3500
Loc_1 cultivar_B  7000  7000
Loc_2 cultivar_B  6000  5500
Loc_3 cultivar_B  5000  3500
```

And this is the error:
`` Error: Column `average.yield` must be length 1 (the group size), not 3 ``

Comment: Simple: instead of `mutate` do `inner_join(mean.yield.loc)`. I believe this is a dupe.

Comment: Simpler: no previous summarised df, all in one go. `data1 %>% group_by(locs) %>% summarise(mean.yield = mean(yield)) %>% inner_join(data1, .)`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Noticed your comment after I posted an answer which is similar to your comment.

Comment: @JasonMathews Don't worry, maybe the OP could use a different approach (without `dplyr`). Besides, I like my second comment more, it doesn't need to pre-compute `mean.yield.loc`.

Comment: thanks for the responses. I like the simpler code without pre-computing `mean.yield.loc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `merge` function.

```
merge(data1,mean.yield.loc, by.x = "locs", by.y = "locs")

  locs   cultivar yield mean.yield
1 Loc_1 cultivar_A  7000       7000
2 Loc_1 cultivar_B  7000       7000
3 Loc_2 cultivar_A  5000       5500
4 Loc_2 cultivar_B  6000       5500
5 Loc_3 cultivar_A  2000       3500
6 Loc_3 cultivar_B  5000       3500
```